# Single textview with two different colors for dynamic text

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview and I want to change the color of word starting with @ to red color and if there is also word with # , I want to change it to black color.Text is not hard coded. How can I do this.Please help me.I have tried with the below code.but the problem is red color is only applied for the first word.

```
String MsgTitle = Details.get(position).getContent();
                String refString;
                String hashString;
                if (MsgTitle.contains(" ")) {
                    refString = MsgTitle.substring(0,
                            MsgTitle.indexOf(' ')).trim();

                    if (String.valueOf(refString.charAt(0)).equals("@")) {
                        refString = refString.replaceFirst("(^@\\w+)",
                                "<font color='#8A0A0A'>$1</font>");
                    } else {
                        refString = refString.replaceAll("(#\\w+)",
                                "<font color='#000000'><b>$1</b></font>");
                    }

                    hashString = MsgTitle.substring(
                            MsgTitle.indexOf(' ') + 1).trim();
                    ((TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textData))
                            .setText(Html.fromHtml(refString
                                    + " "
                                    + hashString
                                            .replaceAll("(#\\w+)",
                                                    "<font color='#000000'><b>$1</b></font>")));
}
```

***Answer for my issue***

```
tring[] str_array = str .split(" ");

            boolean isExists = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    if (str_array[j].equals(str_array[i])) {
                        isExists = true;
                    }
                }
                if (str_array[i].startsWith("@") && !isExists) {
                    str  = str .replace(str_array[i],
                            "<font color='#8A0A0A'>" + str_array[i]
                                    + "</font>");
                } else if (str_array[i].contains("#")) {
                    str  = str .replaceAll(str_array[i],
                            "<font color='#000000'><b>" + str_array[i]
                                    + "</b></font>");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this way..

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            txtHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
            String str = "hello as new kkk @lll llll kkkk mm nn dd #jjj @pppp";

            String[] str_array = str.split(" ");

            for (int i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
                if (str_array[i].startsWith("@")) {
                    str=str.replaceAll(str_array[i], "<font color='red'>" + str_array[i] + "</font>");
                } else if (str_array[i].startsWith("#")) {
                    str=str.replaceAll(str_array[i], "<font color='black'>" + str_array[i] + "</font>");
                }
            }

            txtHeader.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));

        }
```

Comment: Thank you.It's worked.But some texts displayed as @somt..ng and some other texts displayed as @Something..>

Comment: can you post here that string which creating problem for you?

Comment: it just change textcolor not string, so what the problem?  actually not getting your point of view that you wrote in first comment..

Comment: The problem occurs for the string that contains same words with@

Answer (score 1):

Try HTML styling:

```
String data = "<font color=##00FFFF>blue</font> <font color=#FFFF00>yellow</font>";

((TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textData))
                        .setText(Html.fromHtml(data));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by formatting the string from HTML:

```
String text = "<font color=#ff0000>red text</font> <font color=#00ff00>green color</font>";
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

You'll need to do some coding to generate this HTML text from the @ and # tags you've got, but that shouldn't be too hard.

Good luck :)

Edit: 
Here's something that should fix your algorithm. it's only good for finding the red tags, but can easily be extended for the other colors:

(By the way, I didn't test it, so there might be a few glitches here and there... hope you'll be able to work them out tho :P)

```
String text = "lalala @red lalala";
        int indexForRed = text.indexOf("@");
        int indexForSpace = -1;
        String redText;
        String beforeRedText;
        String afterRedText;


        while (indexForRed != -1)
        {
            indexForSpace = text.indexOf(" ", indexForRed);
            redText = text.substring(indexForRed + 1, indexForSpace);           
            beforeRedText = indexForRed > 0 ? text.substring(0, indexForRed - 1) : "";
            afterRedText = indexForSpace < text.length() - 1 ? text.substring(indexForSpace + 1, text.length()) : "";

            text = beforeRedText + "<font color=\"#ff0000\">" + redText + "</font>" + afterRedText;         

            indexForRed = text.indexOf("@", text.indexOf("</font>", indexForSpace));
        }
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Also, you might consider using a different denominator for the other color (instead of #... maybe $,%,^) since # is used to specify the color in the font and it might mix up the whole algorithm. If you must use #, then be sure to search for # before searching for @, and it should work alright.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example to set the text color dynamically:

```
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");  
// make "Lorem" (characters 0 to 5) red  
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, 0);  
textView.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Use indexOf(char c) to get the index of '@' and '#'.

Answer (score 0):

Html.fromHtml is a nasty workaround for things like that, you can use it, by forming peoper html tags and call fromHtml but under the hood that method parses your html and creates spans and uses Spannable interface and this is what you really try

Answer (score 0):

```
String res1[] = {"#11111","#22222","#3333","#4444","#555","#666","#77","#88","#99","#100","#161","#152"};

String aa=(String) (res1[position]+","+res[position]+"---"+des[position]);


if (res1[position].startsWith("#")) {
   aa=aa.replaceAll(res1[position], "<b>" + res1[position] + "</b>");
}
```

**holder.problem.setText(Html.fromHtml(aa));**

In place of **bold** we can use ant tag ex:......ect,.